# Jank-free Tailwind / Alpine.js accordion

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm working on an accordion that uses Tailwind and Alpine.js (2.x) but I can't seem to get the transitions smooth, it's too janky.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
        <ol class="max-w-sm p-4">
            <li class="pb-6 mb-6 border-b" x-data="{isOpen : true }">
                <h3 class="flex text-2xl mb-6" :class="{ 'mb-6': isOpen }">
                    <button class="text-left" type="button" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                    Heading 1
                    </button>
                </h3>
                <div x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" @click.away="isOpen = false">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure rerum in tempore sit ducimus doloribus quod commodi eligendi ipsam porro non fugiat nisi eaque delectus harum aspernatur recusandae incidunt quasi.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="pb-6 mb-6 border-b" x-data="{isOpen : false }">
                <h3 class="flex text-2xl mb-6" :class="{ 'mb-6': isOpen }">
                    <button class="text-left" type="button" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                    Heading 2
                    </button>
                </h3>
                <div x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" @click.away="isOpen = false">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure rerum in tempore sit ducimus doloribus quod commodi eligendi ipsam porro non fugiat nisi eaque delectus harum aspernatur recusandae incidunt quasi.</p>
                </div>
            </li>      
        </ol>
```

Any tips on how to make it smoother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit on 2022-01-06

Accordions (among other components) are now part of official [AlpineJS documentation](http://alpinejs.dev/components). Use them for perfect out of the box accordions.

### Original answer

The main issue regarding smoothness is related to `mb-6` not transitioning. A quick fix is proposed below (using `mt-6` for the child).

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
            <ol class="max-w-sm p-4">
                <li class="pb-6 mb-6 border-b" x-data="{isOpen : true }">
                    <h3 class="flex text-2xl">
                        <button class="text-left" type="button" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                        Heading 1
                        </button>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="mt-6" x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" @click.away="isOpen = false">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure rerum in tempore sit ducimus doloribus quod commodi eligendi ipsam porro non fugiat nisi eaque delectus harum aspernatur recusandae incidunt quasi.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="pb-6 mb-6 border-b" x-data="{isOpen : false }">
                    <h3 class="flex text-2xl">
                        <button class="text-left" type="button" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                        Heading 2
                        </button>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="mt-6" x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" @click.away="isOpen = false">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure rerum in tempore sit ducimus doloribus quod commodi eligendi ipsam porro non fugiat nisi eaque delectus harum aspernatur recusandae incidunt quasi.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>      
            </ol>
```

However, the smoothness is still not great. To achieve something nice & cool, instead of using transition properties and x-show from AlpineJS, use Transition class and play with the max-height from Tailwind instead. You have a nice example [here](https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/zYvRMMw?editors=1000) referenced in [AlpineToolbox](https://www.alpinetoolbox.com/examples/).

Comment: Thanks, the example you linked to was what I was after with a couple of tweaks. 